# Erlang logger config does not respond to log level setting info

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

After starting the Erlang shell with `erl` I create a logger like so

```
4> Config = #{config => #{file => "./info.log"}, level => info}.
#{config => #{file => "./info.log"},level => info}
5> logger:add_handler(myhandler, logger_std_h, Config).
ok
```

Then if I try to log a warning message by `logger:warn("foo").` it shows up in the log file. But if I try an info message by `logger:info("foo").` it does not. Even though the log level has explicitly been set to `info` in the Config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`erl` needs to be started with a kernel parameter to do this.

Starting it with `erl -kernel logger_level info` works as expected.